# How to place a figure on the left?

Tags: graphics

Som[image: I need put the picture like that]

I need to put this image like this, but I can not and I need the image on the left of the page and, next to the image, I have centered text. I tried it with wrapfigure

This is my code

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.15cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{l}{2cm} %this figure will be at the left
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{LogoUES}
\end{wrapfigure}
\begin{center}
 UNIVERSIDAD DE EL SALVADOR \\
 FACULTAD MULTIDISCIPLINARIA ORIENTAL \\
 DEPARTAMENTO DE CIENCIAS NATURALES Y MATEMÁTICA \\
 SECCIÓN DE MATEMÁTICA 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: And I get this]

And I get this

Comment: Show your tried code.

Comment: I showed my code

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Think of it as two adjacent minipages; a smaller one to the left that will contain the picture, and the other is the larger one that will contain information about the school.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.15cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.15\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.85\textwidth}
\begin{center}
 UNIVERSIDAD DE EL SALVADOR \\
 FACULTAD MULTIDISCIPLINARIA ORIENTAL \\
 DEPARTAMENTO DE CIENCIAS NATURALES Y MATEMÁTICA \\
 SECCIÓN DE MATEMÁTICA 
\end{center}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```